# Several Constructors in Java

Tags: java, constructor, bluej

I'm programming a game(on a very basic level) for a school project in java using BlueJ, and I'm trying to split one constructor, containing a lot of information, into two or three separate constructors. The initial code, before my changes looks as follows:

```
public class Game 

//fields omitted.. 
{
    public Game() //initialise game
    {
        createRooms();
    }

    private void createRooms() // initialise rooms and exists and set start room. 
    {
        Room bedRoom, kitchen;

        bedRoom = new Room("in the bedroom");
        kitchen = new Room("in the kitchen");

        bedRoom.setExit("north", kitchen);
        kitchen.setExit("south", bedRoom);

        player = new Player(kitchen);
    }


    //Now, I want to seperate the contructor initialising the exits from the rest. 
    //I do so, by copying this to a new constructor below the createRooms constructor:
    //initial code omitted..
    private void createRooms() // initialise rooms
    {
        Room bedRoom, kitchen;

        bedRoom = new Room("in the bedroom");
        kitchen = new Room("in the kitchen");   
    }

    private void createExits() // initialise room exits and set start room.
    {
        Room bedRoom, kitchen;

        bedRoom.setExit("north", kitchen);
        kitchen.setExit("south", bedRoom);

        player = new Player(kitchen);
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get the error message in the new constructor: "variable bedRoom might not have been initialised". I don't get this, since the variable was initialised in the previous constructor. Can this be solved from the information and code provided above? Thanks in advance!

BR
The Newbie.

Comment: Your constructor is one line. How can you possibly want it to be shorter?

Comment: Each of your functions has a separate, completely unrelated variable.  You want a field in the class.

Comment: You do not even have a real constructor which has any parameters. How would you want it to be shorter?

Comment: There is only one constructor in your class, the others are just private methods.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `bedRoom` is a *local variable* not an attribute, hence you need to assign a value to it when you declare it. Currently, it's uninitialized and it won't even compile, because if it did, it would raise a `NullPointerException` as soon as your code is executed.

If you want to initialize variables inside the constructor so they can be seen everywhere, declare them *outside* as attributes:

```
public class Game {
    Room bedRoom;
    Room kitchen;
}
```

And remove these lines from the other methods:

```
Room bedRoom, kitchen;
```

Comment: No; it's uninitialzed, and will give a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Constructores are supposed to set values to every `final` member variable (which is not directly initialized at declaration). So what you want is not possible.

You may remove the `final` keyword from some member variables, but then they may be `null` which is a problem quite often.

In case you problem is that the constructor has to many parameters, there are (at least) 2 common approaches:

1. split the responsibilities of your class.
   Most likely your class does to much and you could put some of the code to separate classes. There is a good chance that you will end up wich a bunch of classes that you use in sequence so that each classe as very few parameters.
2. use the *Builder Pattern*
   With the builder pattern you create a separate Builder class where you have a separate *setter* method for each constructor parameter. 
   These setter methods usually return `this` (the current Builder instance) so that calls could be chained. like this

   `MyClass theObject = new MyClassBuilder().withA("the A").withB("the B") /*... */ .withZ("the Z").build();`

   The method `build()` checks if all properties are given and then calls the constructor with the lots of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Variables `bedRoom` and `kitchen` have local scope, they don't exist outside the methods. You should declare them as class members. And `player` as well.

Now, you should think twice when you put class member initialization code into a private method. Why? Because that method can be called after construction, and it's going to reset your member variables! The only reason I could think of is you have *a lot* member variables, and the constructor is getting really long.

```
class Game {
    private Room bedRoom;
    private Room kitchen;
    private Player player;

    public Game() {
        // And you should initialize class members directly in the
        // constructor. Most of the time.
        bedRoom = new Room("in the bedroom");
        kitchen = new Room("in the kitchen");
        player = new Player(kitchen);

        connectRooms();
    }

    private void connectRooms() {
        bedRoom.setExit("north", kitchen);
        kitchen.setExit("south", bedRoom);
    }
}
```